# codeigniter pass data to nested view

Tags: php, codeigniter, view

I have done very much research on this topic but I cannot find how i can do this. I am trying to add data to the `$data` parameter in a view that is being called from the controller of another view.  However, any data i add to the `subview` via the `subcontroller` cannot be accessed by the `subview`.  However, when I try to pass data to the subview via the client view, it works just fine.  Most of the fixes on SO seem to reference just calling the `$key in $data['key']` rather than $data so that doesn't seem really relevant here...

I have two classes:

- welcome.php - a page
- welcomemenu.php - a set of controls intended to
  be loaded into welcome.php

Here is my Client Controller (the page that it's on, `welcome.php`), which stores the return val from subview `$welcomemenu` in its own $data array...:

```
<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();      
    }

    function index() {
        //echo 'this is the Welcome index function';
        $data['clienttestdata'] = 'data from welcome.php!';
        $data['welcomemenu'] = $this->load->view('welcome/welcomemenu', $data, true);

        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('pages/welcome', $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');

    }
}
```

And here is the client view ("welcome_view.php" - seems simple enough.  The $welcomemenu var is where I put the returns from my component class...):

```
    <section id="allWelcomeContent" class="mainBody">
        <header id="mainPageHdr" class=mainPageHdr>
            <!-- other stuff from my header -->
        </header>
        <!-- this is where i want to put the welcome menu... -->
        <section id="mainWelcomeContent" class="mainContent">
            <div>
                <?php echo $welcomemenu;?>
            </div>
        </section>
    </section>
```

And here is the Controller for my sub-component `welcomemenu.php`:

```
<?php

class Welcomemenu extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index() {
        $data['menu_items'] = array('About', 'Portfolio', 'Resume', 'Fun', 'Blog'); 
        $data['testdata'] = 'data from welcomemenu.php!';

        $this->load->view('welcome/welcomemenu', $data);
    }
}
```

And lastly:  Here is the sub-view that is supposed to get data from its own controller, but cannot, even though it can take data from a calling client (i.e., the $clienttestdata shows up fine but $testdata doesn't)!

```
<section>
<!-- TODO:  make this element repeatable so content can load from controller and/or model. -->
<div id="divMenuItems">
    <?php echo $clienttestdata;?>
    <?php echo $testdata;?>
</div>
</section>
```

Still i couldn't find any proper solution. if anyone then please give me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're including the welcomemenu partial in your Welcome/index method, you have to remember that the view does not go through its own controller. Instead, its contents are returned as a string and stored as a parameter. It gets all of its own parameters through the ones you send to it via `$data`:

```
$data['welcomemenu'] = $this->load->view('welcome/welcomemenu', $data, true);
```

This view will thus have access to everything in `$data` so far - nothing extra is added through the Welcomemenu controller. So, in the above case, it will have:

```
array
(
   'clienttestdata' => 'data from welcome.php!'
)
```

If you add the parameters you need to `$data` (as `$data['testdata']`), your sub-view will have what it needs.

Comment: OK thank you; I think I follow that logic. However, is this a best practice (i.e., to have the subcontroller's data controlled by the client controller)?  Should I consider refactoring so that the subcontroller can actually put the data into the subview, or should I follow my current course of development?

Comment: The way you're currently doing it is fine - because you're including it within the `Welcome` class, not any other. All you have to remember is to pass it what you need through `$data` or maybe another parameter called `$sub_data` for clarity.

Comment: OK thanks.  I think my problem is that I confuse the index() function of CI/php classes with the constructor of that class.